# In Android AOSP, why different Locale syntax?

Tags: android, locale, android-source

In Android Open Source Project platform, why do:

```
PRODUCT_LOCALES
```

and

```
PRODUCT_SYSTEM_PROPERTIES += ro.localization.locale_filter=<regexp>
```

not use the same Locale syntax?